# Appscript Not Working Across Different Tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below working script but would like to have it working in multiple tabs, instead of having to create several triggers and overload the sheet.

This is the script:

```
function clearSomeCellsReading () {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Reading');
  const sr = 1;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr,21,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat();
  vs.forEach((e,i) => {
    if(e > 29) sh.getRange(i + sr,16,1,3).clearContent();
  })
}
```

Apart from "('Reading')", I have other 20 locations that I would like to incorporate, ie. Bristol, Watford...

All the other tabs are exactly the same to this one, all copies of each other with just different data.

I tried duplicating the script and just changing the tab name but I keep getting errors...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of trigger are you using?

Comment: Please answer Cooper's question. It's unclear if you're trying to have this procedure run on all sheets *at the same time*, or if you're trying to make it available to run for each sheet at separate times.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I was running one trigger for each location. A trigger on change, as the number “29” or more means days passed. Hope this helps. Thank you all for your help! Each tab will run individually as they run different data.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be what you're looking for. If you have some distinct text to identify the Sheets you want to run the procedure on, that would make it dynamic. Otherwise you can specify the exact names of the sheets you want to run it on as shown below.

```
function allSheetsMacro(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const theSheetsToInclude = ["Reading","Bristol","Watford"];
  const allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++){
    var aSheet = allSheets[i];
    if(theSheetsToInclude.includes(aSheet.getName())){
      //or whatever rule to find your sheets.
      clearSomeCellsReading_(aSheet);
    }
  }
}


function clearSomeCellsReading_(sh) {
//original function but being called each time from first function.    
  const sr = 1;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr,21,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat();
  vs.forEach((e,i) => {
    if(e > 29) sh.getRange(i + sr,16,1,3).clearContent();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function clearSomeCellsReading () {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const sr = 1;
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr,21,sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat();
  vs.forEach((e,i) => {
    if(e > 29) sh.getRange(i + sr,16,1,3).clearContent();
  })
}
```

or maybe this:

```
function clearSomeCellsReading() {
  const shts = ['Reading', 'others'];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (~shts.indexOf(sh.getName())) {
    const sr = 1;
    const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 21, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1).getValues().flat();
    vs.forEach((e, i) => {
      if (e > 29) sh.getRange(i + sr, 16, 1, 3).clearContent();
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Cooper what's that `~` doing in your `if` statement? It appears you're doing something similar to mine by testing if the sheet name exists in the array (wouldn't `includes` be ideal? You know more about this than me, so if this is a stupid question sorry.

Comment: @pgSystemTester [Bitwise Not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Comment: Any technical reason to use that instead of `includes` or are they basically just doing the same thing and that's your preferred method?

Comment: It's just something I use a lot.  Sometimes I actually want to know what the index is.

Comment: @pgSystemTester thank you so much for your help with this. Could you help in the if statement that mentions 29, as It's deleting some rows that it shouldn't, can it be more than 29 but less than 50 please? Thank you ever so much

Comment: You should accept an answer first before asking people to do more help for you.